# Inserir barra de erro padrão no gráfico de barras

Tags: ggplot2, r

Como posso inserir no gráfico abaixo a barra de erro padrão?

Segue os dados e o gráfico como modelo desejado.

```
resp = c(16,18,17,17,18,15,17,16)
trat = factor(rep(1:2, each = 4), label = c("Roço Abril","Testemunha"))
df <- data.frame(tratamento = c("Testemunha", "Roço Abril"),
             media = c(17,16.5),
             posicao = c(2,2),
             tukey = c("17 a", "16.5 a"),
             ep = c(0.73))
ggplot(df, aes(y = media, x = tratamento)) +
geom_col(alpha = 0.7) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,25), breaks = seq(0,25,5)) +
geom_text(aes(label = tukey), size = 4, vjust = -0.2)+
ggtitle("Contagem perfilhos 30 DAR")+
theme_bw(base_size = 11) +
xlab("Tratamento") + 
ylab("Número de perfilhos / metro")
```

[image: figura modelo]

Comment: Mas onde está a informação sobre o erro padrão no `df`? Ele só possui as colunas `tratamento`, `media`, `posicao` e `tukey`.

Comment: Inseri a informação do erro padrão junto ao df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ter as barras de erro, use `geom_errorbar` com `ymin` e `ymax` iguais a `media ± ep` e atribua os valores que não dependem dos dados (cor, espessura da linha e largura das barras) fora de `aes`.
Também alterei a coordenada `y` do texto de modo a não estar sobreposto às barras.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(tratamento = c("Testemunha", "Roço Abril"),
                 media = c(17,16.5),
                 posicao = c(2,2),
                 tukey = c("17 a", "16.5 a"),
                 ep = c(0.73))

ggplot(df, aes(x = tratamento, y = media)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = media - ep, ymax = media + ep), 
                color = "red", size = 1, width = 0.25) +  
  geom_text(aes(y = media + ep, label = tukey), size = 4, vjust = -0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,25), breaks = seq(0,25,5)) +
  ggtitle("Contagem perfilhos 30 DAR")+
  xlab("Tratamento") + 
  ylab("Número de perfilhos / metro") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 11)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>